# Counting empty values in dataframe: scala spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

Assuming that I have a dataframe `df` which has multiple columns `column1`,`column2` .. and I want to find the count of empty values in each column. A way to do it is to go from each column like:

```
df.filter($"column1" !== "").count
df.filter($"column2" !== "").count
                .
                .
```

But is there a way to do it in one line?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use some kind of aggregation and build a new DataFrame:

```
  df.agg(
      sum(when($"column1" !== "", 1).otherwise(0)),
      sum(when($"column2" !== "", 1).otherwise(0))
      )
```

EDIT: If you have a lot of columns, try something like this:

```
val ncols=2
val cols = (1 to ncols)
  .map(i=> sum(when(col("column"+i)!=="",1).otherwise(0)))

df.agg(cols.head,cols.tail:_*)
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but my main question is how to avoid to write `column1`, `column2` ... Cant use this code if i have 100 of columns or more.